# How to resolve "Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/rule-name' was not found"

Tags: javascript, typescript, build

I'm trying to add TypeScript compilation to an existing Javascript project.

AFAIK this is supposed to be possible (even easy), and you can incrementally spread TS through the codebase.  Unfortunately this isn't what I'm seeing - after adding typescript and trying to start the project, I get this error for every single file in the project:

`Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/rule-name' was not found`

[image]

There is no instance of the string `rule-name` anywhere in my source code.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "types"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

I have tried adding `"checkJs": false` to the config and restarting but that doesn't change anything.

I haven't been able to track down anything online about this "rule-name" problem.  It really looks like this is a placeholder text of some sort, but I can't find the source.

Can anybody suggest anything that might help me get this project to build?

Comment: This is not an error from Typescript but from ESLint. I'm not sure of how you added Typescript, but if you included ESLint by accident, then it might need some setup if you already had something installed for JS.

Comment: Shared my solution here — https://stackoverflow.com/a/77447319/6778546 — check this out, might help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're using [`react-app-rewired`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) and [`customize-cra`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra), you need to make sure you use `disableEsLint` from the latter; otherwise linting errors become typescript errors and prevent compilation.

Comment: IMHO, that's the whole point of linting errors. Get rid of the lint, or change the configuration, rather than disabling it.

Comment: To compensate for disabling ESLint in that way when I'm stuck with `react-app-rewired` and `customize-cra` for a while, I edit the "start" script in package.json to `"eslint --fix \"src/**/*.js\" && react-app-rewired start"`. So when I execute `npm start`, it runs eslint command first then, if it succeeds, start compiling the app.

Answer (score 34):

The error that you have is coming from ESLint and means that you have a rule in your `.eslintrc` which doesn't exist in any of your plugins. This could have happened if you followed the usage guide for `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` but didn't replace the placeholder `rule-name` with an actual rule name as seen here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

Answer (score 8):

For those who do not want to just disable ESLint but make it work, running `npm update` could resolve the issue. In my case updating just `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` was not enough but after `npm update` warnings dissapeared and ESLint was up and running.

Also worth to keep in mind this higlight from package authors:

> It is important that you use the same version number for @typescript-eslint/parser and @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin.

More detailed packages setup on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin).

Comment: Packages matching versions!?!?! THAT'S CRAZY TALK!

Answer (score 8):

For me, it was enough to add plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended
in the .eslintrc file.

```
"extends": [
  ...<otherExtentions>...
  "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the rule is not declared in your eslint.json file
Add the following line to your RULES in esling.json file

"@typescript-eslint/object-curly-spacing" : "off"

Refer the image below to know more

[Refer this image to add the rule to eslint.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmK4M.png)

Answer (score 2):

As of now the "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" has removed this rule in their v6 release.

See here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/5973

You can fix this by replacing it with the rule "import/no-duplicates", which is part of the "eslint-plugin-import" package.

See here: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-duplicates.md

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm upgrading from Angular 15 - 16 and in my `eslintrc.json`  `@typescript-eslint` was not added inside `plugins`.

So, I have just added and it's working!

```
// eslintrc.json
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": [
      "tsconfig.json",
      "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    ],
    "createDefaultProgram": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "sonar",
    "rxjs",
    "jsdoc",
    "@typescript-eslint" // This was missing ;)
  ],
  "extends": [...],
  "rules": [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that ... the rules were actually no longer valid and deprecated:

```
ESLint: Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface' was not found.(@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface)
ESLint: Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define' was not found.(@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define)
ESLint: Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/quotes' was not found.(@typescript-eslint/quotes)
ESLint: Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/semi' was not found.(@typescript-eslint/semi)
```

See if you can find your rule in [this list](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/), and if you do - just remove it from your `.eslintrc.json` file.