# Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention was not found'

Tags: typescript, eslint, lint

I'm trying to deploy a front-end app using typescript and npm. When I try running a build, I get multiple errors stating "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention was not found". I verified that my node_modules are up-to-date and even checked the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin module (which is version 5.30.6) and @typescript-eslint/parser (version 5.30.6). I'm not sure why this is happening or what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

My package.json file looks like:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@jest/types": "27.5.1",
    "@swc/core": "1.2.215",
    "@swc/jest": "0.2.21",
    "@types/jest": "27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "16.11.44",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.30.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.30.6",
    "esbuild": "0.12.29",
    "eslint": "8.19.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "lerna": "6.1.0",
    "nx": "15.2.4",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  },
```

Tried running npm update to each of my node packages and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I used official information, [from here](https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started#step-2-configuration) for instance, and provided missing `parser` property value for "@typescript-eslint/parser", and value for "@typescript-eslint" in `plugins` property (array) of my root `.eslintrc.json` — this update helped to get rid of the stupid errors